# Is there any way to get alphabetical numbering of rows in ssrs instead of numerical numbering?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

What I need (alphabetical numbering of rows-highlighted in bold(serial column)):

[image]

I have tried converting the output of rownumber function into string, But nothing seems to work as I don't have any idea.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a bit of custom code.

Go to the Report Properties, click the "Code" tab and paste the following code into the custom code window.

```
Public Function GetRowLetter(RowNum As Integer) As String

' stick the RowNum in a variable that we can reduce until it's zero

Dim r As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Dim s As String ' holds result

s = ""
r = RowNum

' we start at the right side so if the rownum is 28 we want to be back AB
' need to get 'B' first

Do While RowNum > 0

    r = Int((RowNum - 1) / 26)
    i = (RowNum - 1) Mod 26
    s = Chr(i + 65) & s

    RowNum = r
Loop

GetRowLetter = s

End Function
```

This will give "A" for 1, "B" for 2 etc, then it will give "AA" for 27, "AB" or 28 etc...

If you want to return lower case letters instead, swap the `65` for `98`

In your report set the textbox value expression to

```
=Code.GetRowLetter(RowNumber("myDataSetName"))
```

swap out `myDataSetName` with the name of your dataset or scope you want to apply it to. Remember the dataset and scope names are case sensitive and must be surrounded by quotes ( " )

Comment: Thanks @Alan . I will try this.